# Images in tabbar navigator

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, expo, tabbar

I have a tabBar navigator and i want to replace the icons with images, it's working but the activeTintColor won't change when focused although it's set in the navigationOptions, here is the code:

**TabBarIcon component**

```
export default class TabBarIcon extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Image
       source={this.props.source}
       tintColor={this.props.focused ? Colors.tabIconSelected : Colors.tabIconDefault}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

**Icon in tabBarNavigator**

```
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => (
    <Image
      focused={focused}
      source={require('/assets/images/icon.png')}
      tintColor={tintColor}
    />
  ),
```

Answer (score 15):

For the image, try setting it up this way

**Icon in tabBarNavigator**

```
tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
        const image = focused
        ? require('./image/HomeActive.png')
        : require('./image/HomeInactive.png')
        return (
            <Image
                source={image}
                style={{height:36, width:24}}
            />
        )
    }
```

and set `activeTintColor and inactiveTintColor` under `tabBarOptions`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what Colors is or where it is passed, is it a global variable?
try this:

```
export default class TabBarIcon extends React.Component {
  onTintColor = (focused) => {
   if (focused) {
     return Colors.tabIconSelected  
   } 
   return Colors.tabIconDefault
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Image
       source={this.props.source}
       tintColor={this.props.focused && 
         this.onTintColor(this.props.focused)
       }/>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do?
If you want to use the TintColor ptoperty described here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/bottom-tab-navigator.html , you also need to use activeTintColor and inactiveTintColor . That works for labels, if you want to use Images, then there is no need to pass the tintcolor since you are overriding it in your component

**TabBarIcon component**

```
    export default class TabBarIcon extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Image
       source={this.props.source}
       tintColor={this.props.focused ? Colors.tabIconSelected : Colors.tabIconDefault} //you are setting tintcolor based on this.props.focused
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Thats good

```
tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => (
    <Image
      focused={focused}
      source={require('/assets/images/icon.png')}
      //tintColor={tintColor} //there is no need for this
    />
  ),
```

Comment: i don't know if i understood your problem